# gcp terraform assign publish role for a specific role on a pub/sub topic only

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to use terraform to setup publish rights on a specific gcp pub/sub topic only rather than the whole project.  At the moment I could not find a way to do this.  I can do this at the `"google_project_iam_custom_role"` level but this is for the project as a whole.  Is this possible in terraform?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @guillaume blaquiere use PubSub IAM module, to grant a specific user with publisher access, provide `role = roles/pubsub.publisher` see [reference](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control#roles). Your terraform should look like:

```
resource "google_pubsub_topic_iam_binding" "binding" {
  project = "project-id-here"
  topic = "topic-name-here"
  role = "roles/pubsub.publisher"
  members = [
    "user:jane@example.com",
  ]
}
```

Comment: This really helped me, after hours of struggling

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grant permission at PubSub level (the resource level), you need to use the IAM module at the PubSub level. Have a look to the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/pubsub_topic_iam)